# how can i save a cell aray in matlab for ever?my project about finger vein identification

Tags: matlab

How can I save  cell array in matlab when the program is over, that the programm running again use the same previous cell array?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901407/cell-aray-in-matlab… ? There are probably other StackExchange sites which are more suitable to ask this type of questions.

Comment: i have project and i need to save a cell aray of finger vein images for ever

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [h5write](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5write.html) command to save the cell array to a file in the HDF5 format. Then, load it via [h5read](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5read.html).

See also the [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command which outputs a Matlab binary file which can be loaded with [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the command

```
save('filename')
```

which saves all of the variables in your workspace to a .m file in the directory of your program. If you only want a specific variable saved (call it X), then you can write

```
save('filename','X')
```

See http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html for documentation.

You can retrieve the variables when you later open up your script again by using

```
load('filename')
```

See http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html for documentation.

In the future, please ask such questions in Stack Overflow instead.